# How to show catch error message in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#

How to show catch error message in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock?
below is my button click event.like we can get error message in label by using ex.message so how to use this in alert popup message box?

```
 public void IssueDelete()
  {
   try
    {
      //open the db connection if it is closed...  
       if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           connection.Open();
        int issueId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlComplaintDelete.SelectedValue);
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "sp_IssueDelete";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationId", lblUploadRegistrationId.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@issueId", issueId);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Issue Deleted Succesfully');", true);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Cannot Delete');", true);
     }  
     finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
     {
      if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      connection.Close();
     }
  }
protected void btnComplaintDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         IssueDelete();            
        }
```

Comment: where you caught error in C# code or javascript?

Comment: not getting any error but message box not shwoing.

Comment: Where you have the RegisterClientScriptBlock statement?

Comment: what you mean? i couldnt understood

Comment: Do you have this statement in page_load, is it !Page.IsPostback block etc

Comment: no not have.no need na

Comment: Can you show the event / Method where you have this statement?

Comment: You can add in your question

Comment: @Adil I added above,please check there.

Comment: Do you send ajax call to delete?

Comment: no not used any ajax code.

Comment: Your javascript related code is working fine here. Is javascript enabled in the browser you are testing? Also debug the code to see if your ScriptManager statement executes.

Comment: Dear Adil yes I know this is working properly but after add ex.message into that script then its not displaying.so i want to display ex.message in alert message box..now got it?

Comment: check my answer, and let me know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably breaking the javascript for alert that you register. You might be getting single or double quote *that* could also break the javascript. Concatenate the `ex.Message` properly and remove any single/double quote from exception message.

```
try
{
   //Your code
   //throw new Exception("he'\"");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Cannot Delete Exception Message: " + ex.Message.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "") + "');", true);
}
finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
{
   if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @asma, thanks for your patience as I asked you so many questions

Comment: Inshallah if like you people will help then i am always happy to keep learning.

Comment: The chances of getting right answer is directly proportional to quality of question, so go through this, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask